# Generic utility to display alerts out of the Windows sys tray

Tags: windows

I've got a cygwin script that monitors some files.  From this cygwin script I would like to display alerts from the Windows systray.  Kind of like the ones that are shown in outlook.  (Appear then disappear without requiring user to close them).

Was wondering if there was a generic command line utility out there to display such alerts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) - it does that, but you may need a additional [script installed](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/growlnotify.aspx) to pass on the alerts to growl via CLI. The [apps page](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/apps.aspx) also mentions ruby and perl libraries